# Spaces that are locally Euclidean

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to get my head around what it means to be locally Euclidean. I can see how the discrete topology and the n-sphere are locally Euclidean, but what about say the trivial topology an the n-torus?

The n-torus is the unit circle cross itself n times. I can see how the unit circle is locally Euclidean, so is the product of locally Euclidean spaces locally Euclidean also?

As for the trivial topology, I'm not sure where to start...would not the empty set and the whole space in the trivial topology be open in R^n with the standard topology?

Comment: The trivial (“indiscrete”) topology won’t ever be locally Euclidean (except on a singleton space), ’cause it’s not Hausdorff (among other deficiencies).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Lubin. Although, could you please clear up something for me? I thought that for something to be a manifold it has to be locally Euclidean, Hausdorff and second countable, but I thought locally Euclidean, relies on just mapping open sets in some space to open sets in R^n?

Comment: I am not a topologist, but for a space $X$ to be locally Euclidean I believe that every point $x\in X$ must have an open neighborhood that is homeomorphic to an open subset of Euclidean space. In trivial topology, the only neighborhood of $x\in X$ is $X$ itself, and this is not homeomorphic to an open subset of an $E^n$, ’cause (for instance) it’s not even Hausdorff.

Comment: Oh, right, so you mean there cannot be a homeomorphism between the trivial topology and R^n simply because the trivial topology is not Hausdorff, but R^n is.

Comment: Also, as for my other question, can I say that the n-torus is locally Euclidean since it is the product of locally Euclidean spaces (i.e. the circle S^1)?

Comment: yes, that looks sound, but remember I am not a topologist.

Comment: Righto, no worries. And thank you for al your help.